# Qt char* to QString

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, char, qstring

I am trying to convert `char*` to `QString`. It should be a trivial task but the problem is, I am having the following input:

```
item    char [512] "N"  char [512]
    [0] 78 'N'  char
    [1] 0 '\0'  char
    [2] 73 'I'  char
    [3] 0 '\0'  char
    [4] 70 'F'  char
    [5] 0 '\0'  char
    [6] 84 'T'  char
    [7] 0 '\0'  char
    [8] 89 'Y'  char
    [9] 0 '\0'  char
    [10]    0 '\0'  char
```

Notice the null character after each character '\0'. Simply trying to convert it just yields the string **"N"** where as it should result into string **"NIFTY"**.

I am not sure if it is unicode or Ansi `string` (in fact I don't know much about it). Can anyone please sort out what is going wrong here or what am I missing?

Comment: Seems to be unicode. Try `wchar_t`.

Comment: It does seem to be Unicode (UTF-16 to be precise). But that would require another trailing '\0' byte. If that's missing you have a problem.

Comment: Casting to `QChar*` might well work, it would be better to get the data into the right type in the first place though. I think you need to go back a step and show us where you got the data in the first place. Apart from anything else you would learn a bit more about ANSI and Unicode.

Comment: Scratch that, QChar* didn't work for me. QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)buffer) however did, but you need one more 0 char at the buffer end to form a valid zero termination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    char * chr = "N\0I\0F\0T\0Y\0\0";
    QString str = QString::fromUtf16((ushort*)(chr));
    qDebug() << str;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 char name[13] = "StudyTonight";


 int namelen = strlen(name);

 QString  result = QString::fromUtf8((const char *)name,namelen);

 qDebug() << result
```

Comment: You should care to explain why you think it solves the askers problem (but I'm rather sure it won't work this way, so you should re-check your answer and your assumptions).