# Cast char* to QString by c style casting

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

int main()
{   
    char aaa[] = {"abcdefg"};
    QString bbb(QString::fromLatin1(aaa));
    qDebug()<<bbb;
    qDebug()<<((QString)aaa); //dangerous way
    qDebug()<<(reinterpret_cast<QString>(aaa)); //dangerous way

    return a.exec();
}
```

As long As I know, this may cause some undefined behavior, yet the codes work
How could the c-style cast work?

- os : win7 64
- compiler : mingw4.8.2
- Qt : 5.2

edit : 
Is this a safe operation?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used?rq=1

Comment: It works because Qt defines this cast and it's being used a lot as implicit cast for example in `someStuff.setText ("abcdefghj")`. If you would cast it to pointer to `QString` though that would be truly dangerous and wouldn't work ofc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

qt defines conversion from `char*` to `QString` using a constructor

this means that the c-style cast `((QString)aaa)` is well defined (through the `static_cast` mechanism which tries constructors) though dangerous in terms of encodings.

You can disable this by defining `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is : Is there a satefy way to cast char* into QString ? Because this question already has an answer ...

[Qt char* to QString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153281/qt-char-to-qstring)

Kind regards

Comment: I know the safe way, what I want to know is how could c style cast work?

Comment: @user3518786 by sheer luck.

Comment: C style casts should be avoided in C++. I never encountered situation when it was needed except laziness (it's shorter to write then static_cast, const_cast, etc.). Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

*"Is this a safe operation?"*

No. C-style casting in C++ is not generally considered as safe operation. Reason? There is a lots of different kinds of casts and using C-style cast means you tell the compiler that it should select one of them. Problem is that this might lead to different result than you wanted. One chapter in "C++ Coding Standards : Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices" is about that.

---

Example imagine this:

```
class Based { ... }

class Derived : Based { ... }
```

and now source file #1:

```
class Based;
class Derived;

Derived* boo();

Based* foo1()
{
    Derived *a = boo();
    Based *b = (Based*)a;
    return b;
}
```

source #2:

```
#include "Based.h" // Contains definition of Based class
#include "Derived.h" // Contains definition of Derived class

Derived* boo();

Based* foo2()
{
    Derived *a = boo();
    Based *b = (Based*)a;
    return b;
}
```

Both sources will compile! But `foo1()` uses different kind of cast then `foo2()`! First case is bad and will work only in exceptional cases (but even this is not defined by standard).

In other words, in `foo1()` you tell the compiler "treat pointer of `Derived` as if it would be pointer of `Based`", but in the second case you tell the compiler "cast `Derived` to it's parent, `Based`".

`foo1()` might randomly crash or lead into very weird behavior of your code.

And btw. your compiler will probably never warn you about that. So, avoid C-style casting!